# Is there a language-agnostic term for things imported by default, analoguous to Rust's prelude?

Tags: module, language-agnostic, terminology

Many programming languages import (or whatever the relevant term in the language is) some things by default, even if this is often hidden from the developer. Rust calls the list of imports it does the prelude. This being a helpful term, I am wondering - is there an equivalent term in other languages, or better yet, a term that is somewhat-commonly used across languages?

Comment: Haskell is in the same boat, using `Prelude` - https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html

Comment: interesting question, will keep an eye on this.